Using Pi Pico as Access Control
I am designing a Access Control System based around a Pi Pico microcontroller. I took some Circuitry classes in college and I remember blowing multiple chips trying to get everything right. My profession is all software so this is my first step into the hardware world.
Any advice is helpful but I am a beginner so please softly.
I have a 12V Electric Strike Lock. And a 12V Weigand Reader. All the Pico logic is done at 3.3 volts and 12 volts will damage it. I want to know if my electrical diagram properly implements stepping the logic voltage down from 12V to 3.3 and If my transistor to switch the lock on and off will work.
Problem 1. CD74HC4050M96: I believe this device is classified as a shifter and that It will take the input on 5A And 6A and change then to 3.3. volts on 5Y and 6Y respectively.
Problem 2. P2N2222A: For this one I looked up the spec sheet on the Electric Strike. it is 12V with a max draw of 210 mA. I had a bit of trouble understanding how to calculate what the power draw would need to be on the Pico to achieve this.
Bonus Thoughts: I have also seen people use flyback diodes across the strike terminals. Is this best practice or is it more of an extra safety thing


replace your 2222 with a logic-level n-channel mosfet, like the irlz44n. This eliminates a few rough spots and simplifies construction as it has a built-in body diode and draws no real current through the gate that you drive with the pi. you could also use an optocoupler instead of the cd74 stuff.

A series-base resistor should be added to transistor strike driver. A fly-back diode (D1) should certainly be added to its collector. You're asking PICOW for a lot of drive to this transistor's base. You might consider replacing it with a logic-level N-channel MOSfet. I would expect that U5 (+12V to +5V converter) would include a capacitor between its +12V input and its GND input to absorb the strike solenoid's dumped energy via the flyback diode (D1):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
 74HC4050 should have unused logic input pins tied to a known logic level, rather than left to float. You can tie them to GND or to the VDD voltage on pin #1 (not both!). This involves pins 3,5,7,9.
Is BELL+ and BELL- input or output? It is suspicious that these are connected to PICO directly, when the reader is powered with +12V. You should ensure that BELL is completely isolated from the +12V power source.
RPI suggest that 3V3out on pin #36 should not be expected to power other stuff. I suppose a 74HC4050 won't be an excessive load that might cause over-heating of PICO's internal 3.3V regulator.


It appears so, 74HC4050 should take in 12V logic and output 3.3V logic. However, the input logic threshold is somewhere between 1V and 2V. Anything below 1V is logic low and anything above 2V is logic high. So whether your system can work with those input voltages in an useful fashion is up to you.

Transistors are usually not driven with power but current, so power is irrelevant here. However, there is no current limiting base resistor. Logic high output will likely damage the transitor and/or the Raspberry Pi output pin. Also, to drive 210mA load, the base needs as a rule of thumb something like 21mA. This is generally that's a huge amount, and to be within specs, the RP2040 IO pin strength is said to be 12mA. However it looks like it could work at 3.3V with the highest strength setting to provide enough to drive the transistor base, but frankly it would be bad practive in general.

Bonus question about diodes: Inductive loads stores energy into magnetic field when current passes through it. When you turn off the transistor, the magnetic field acts as a generator to keep pushing current through the transistor, possibly reaching hundreds of volts. It is possible you can only turn on the transistor on only once, as turning it off without a diode or other flyback protection may destroy it. And the diode is a trade-off. It is usually the first thing that people put there to protect the transistor, but it is by far the worst solution for dissipating the energy of the inductive load, and for example slowly opening relay contacts may wear out early when coil is driven with transistor and just a diode for suppressing the kickback. A diode may work for you but it's just an example how difficult it is to design a robust device that is supposed to work as a facility access control system without getting damage from external connections.


